# Function [with generic data types]? in Scala. How do I get this right?

Tags: scala, type-systems

I am trying to pick some Scala and among the interesting features I found the function with 
generic (input types)? particularly useful. However trying the following code,

```
def recFunc[A](xs: List[A], base : () => A) : A = if (xs.isEmpty) base() else xs.head + recFunc(xs.tail, base)
```

I get the annoying error written below:

```
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[A]
 required: List[String]
   def recFunc[A](xs: List[A], base : () => A) : A = if (xs.isEmpty) base() else xs.head + recFunc(xs.tail.asInstanceOf[List[A]], base)
```

How on earth, the type inference system came up with A == String and throws this exception.  Can it be that I got completely wrong the use of this construction?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is that you invoke + for a generic type A. The compiler tries to infer something that uses + (like String) and you get the error. I also don't understand what you want to achieve with the +.

Comment: I just wanted to write a recursive function that sums Strings or Ints or Doubles

Comment: So, how can I come up with such function?

Comment: Then you need to set a certain upper bound for A, meaning A needs to be a subclass of something so that + is defined for it. e.g `[A <: Int]` But to be honest i can't think of a way to do this for Int, String and Doubles at the same time.

Comment: Don't worry. It is simply not a very useful feature anyway. Thanks for your answer, it was very enlightening!

Comment: You forgot to mention that I've got completely wrong the use of this construction ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't guarantee that the method `+` is available for type `A`. So, the compiler convert `A` into `String`.

One solution consist of using typeclasses.

```
trait Addable[A] {
    def plus(x: A, y: A): A
}

recFunc[A:Addable]…
```

You may take a look at spire, short intro here : http://typelevel.org/blog/2013/07/07/generic-numeric-programming.html

Comment: What a fantastic answer! Thank you so much for your completeness.

Comment: def sum[A<:Addable[A]](xs: List[A], base : ()=>A) : A = if (xs.isEmpty) base() else xs.head + sum(xs.tail, base). Simply lovely!

Comment: @poissonbreaker Note that Scala standard library has `Numeric`, `Integral` and `Fractional` type classes, which provide basic arithmetic methods as well. No need to define `Addable` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `+` method on `A`, but there's no guarantee that `A` has such a method. There are two ways to get around this: inheritance or type classes.

With inheritance, it would be a simple matter of finding a common ancestor to all desired classes that includes the methods you want, then you'd write `[A <: CommonAncestor]`. Unfortunately, as a result of the effort to make Scala interoperable with Java and general JVM restrictions, the numeric primitives share no such ancestor.

We are left, then, with type classes. The expression "type class" comes from Haskell, and the idea is that you can group different types into a class that share some common properties. The main difference between that and inheritance is that a type class is open to extension: you can easily add any type to such a class.

Scala does not have direct type class support. Instead, we use a "type class pattern" to simulate it. Basically, we create a class -- the type class -- that contains the methods we desire. Next, we create instances of that class for each type we desire to support. Finally, we pass those instances *implicitly*, which makes it the compiler's job to find the instance required.

In your example, we could do this:

```
// Our type class
class Addable[T] {
  def plus(a: T, b: T): T
}

// Or Int instance
object AddableInt {
  class AddableInt extends Addable[Int] {
    def plus(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
  }
  implicit val addableInt = new AddableInt
}

// Make the implicit available
import AddableInt._

// Make recFunc use it
def recFunc[A](xs: List[A], base : () => A)(implicit addable: Addable[A]): A = 
  if (xs.isEmpty) base() else addable.plus(xs.head, recFunc(xs.tail, base))

// call recFunc
recFunc(List(1, 2, 3), () => 0)
```

There are many ways to improve this, such as using implicit class and context bounds. Please, see the [Scala wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) on Stack Overflow for more information on implicits and context bounds (sessions 23 and 19, respectively).

Now, it happens that Scala already has context bounds for basic arithmetic, and even some extra tricks using view bounds to make it usage seamless. Here's how you can make it work with the standard library alone:

```
import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._
def recFunc[A : Numeric](xs: List[A], base : ()=>A) : A = 
    if (xs.isEmpty) base() else xs.head + recFunc(xs.tail, base)
```

See also the [Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric) scaladoc, though it's really low on examples.

Comment: I wish something like this was possible: `def recFunc[A <: { def + (value : A) : A }]...`

Comment: Also thought about `Numeric` but he wanted Strings as well.